# How can you read RGBA using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, rgba

I'm currently reading BGR values from a set of images,

I have used a variety of imread flags however i cant seem to pull it as BGRA.

my current code is

```
import cv2
import os

#returns an list of images, list of x, list of y, list of BGR
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename),flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images
```

This returns an `array([245, 247, 255], dtype=uint8)` where i was expecting something like `array([245, 247, 255, 0.2], dtype=uint8)`

Comment: What's the type of images in the folder?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto they are all .jpg images, 360x640pix

Comment: JPG doesn't have any alpha channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` doesn't *add* an alpha channel, it only *preserve* the existing one.

Since your images are all JPG format, you would need to add the forth channel by `cvtColor`:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
```

Comment: this has worked and the alpha channel is all 255 which makes sense if jpg images only contain RGB as you mentioned. I'm attempting to do background subtraction on a mp4 video and so i assume i have lost information by converting it to jpg frames. Do you happen to know what image type would be lose the least information?

Comment: @TisButaScratch No you've not lost any information by converting a mp4 to jpg frames as neither a mp4 nor a jpg has an alpha channel. The frames are all opaque.

Comment: You do lose information when converting to JPG, because it is a lossy compressed format. Best to use a format that does  not use lossy compression, such as PNG or TIFF with LZW or ZIP or no compression.